# Dynamically remove element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom

I'm saddled with a task at my work place to work on a dashboard.

On load of the page, i'm required to send a request to  an endpoint to get the list of all organization and display them in a select input field as seen below
[image]

- I'm also to pick the first option and send another request to get the details for the dashboard as seen below
  [image]

The major issue is,

- Once  there is a change in the first select field as seen in image 1, am to remove the rest next dropdowns and replace with the data supplied to create a second select field and populate the options with the new data.

NOTE: If I already have 5 dropdown select fields and the user change an option in the 2nd one, I'm to remove the 3,4 and 5th one from the DOM and create a new select field (Making only 3 that will now be in existence).

Incase you dont understand, i will be glad to explain to you via google meet for better understanding

```
//Dropdown container for the whole SELECT
  let townhalls_select = document.querySelectorAll(
    ".townhall_select_field"
  );
  townhalls_select.forEach(function (div, index) {
    div.addEventListener("change", function () {
      let position = index + 1; // Adding 1 to match human-readable index (starting from 1)

      const townhalls_container = Array.from(townhalls_select);
      if (position == 1) {
        // Remove elements after the third occurrence (index greater than 2)
        townhalls_container.slice(position + 1).forEach((element) => {
          element.remove();
        });
      } else {
        // Remove elements after the third occurrence (index greater than 2)
        townhalls_container.slice(position).forEach((element) => {
          element.remove();
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching this in a way that is not compatible with using React. You  have failed to understand how React works and how to do things with it.

React handles the actual DOM manipulation for you. You return JSX elements, based on the props passed into the component and internal state of the component, that describe what the DOM should look like, and React takes care of removing, modifying or adding DOM elements as required.

You will face all sorts of issues if you try to "fight" with React about DOM manipulation.

I highly recommend you read the new React docs at https://react.dev/.